# proc logistic / proc qlim ... different results SAS

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

I have this simple data, with ***qualitative*** variable `x1`

```
proc iml;
y={1,0,1,0,1};
x1={0,1,0,0,1};
CREATE newdata var{y x1};append;close newdata;
run;
quit;
```

I use these two `proc` for estimating the parameters in SAS

```
PROC LOGISTIC DESCENDING DATA = newdata;
 class x1;
     MODEL y = x1;
RUN;
```

and

```
 PROC qlim DATA = newdata;
     MODEL y = x1/discrete(d=logit);
RUN;
```

I don't understand, why I have ***different results***.

***Note*** that, if I delete `class x1`, then I have the same results.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `proc logistic` uses "effect coding" for classification variables. The parameters represent the difference between the class effect and the average effect across all classes. If you want to interpret the parameters on your class variable as dummy variables, you could use `(param=ref ref='0')` in your `class` statement.